# How to get specific file details under windows?

Tags: java, php, windows, vb.net, properties

Which is the easiest way I could get the file details / properties under windows?

I am not talking about common properties (such as file size, creation date), but the ones  written by variuos software. In my particular case I need to get the detail called "Date taken" for a jpg image file.

I could use PHP, Java or VB.NET, whatever is easier.

My final goal: I have a bunch of images I took with different versions of Android on my phone. They are all named with different naming convention, most of them just something like IMG_[consecutive_numbers].jpg. So I want to rename them all, but for that I need their original creation date, and since I have moved them from my pc to the phone and back so many times, I cannot trust the "creation date" property. I found that all of them have a property which was set by the camera called "Date taken", which is still intact and valid.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.:

This is what I need:

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the exif data in the images?

Comment: Forgive my incompetence, but I don't know what is exif data. Check my post, I've attached a screenshot.

Comment: is there something wrong with the last mod date?

Comment: I don't really know why, but the date is invalid on most of the images..

Comment: *"I could use PHP, Java or VB.NET, whatever is easier."*  I imagine .NET would provide a built-in API to get that information.  Java does not.

Comment: I believe so myself, but that's why I am asking here, becouse I don't even know what are these details called, and how to search for such an API.

Comment: It can be changed or edited, and being able to retrieve it doesn't help in the softpiece evaluation. Maybe good as a technique put up in blogs for references.

Comment: Yes, exif data is what you want.  Look around at taglib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php

Answer (score 2):

I believe the photo you have posted actually shows something pulled from the exif data.

Knowing this you can use any language that has the ability to extract the exif data.

For java their is no native way so you would use a library such as http://www.drewnoakes.com/code/exif/

I am a ava developer so I have provided a Java option; however, this can be done in any language.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim finfo As New System.IO.FileInfo(fdialog.FileName)
```

now you can play around with all the fileinfo attribures.
regards ...